# How to print euro sign from c console app using gnome terminal

Tags: c, utf-8, gnome-terminal, euro

I am trying to print the euro sign on the console in the Gnome Terminal app through a c console application. My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wctype.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"UTF-8");
    wchar_t w_char1 = '€';
    wprintf(L"%x\n", w_char1);
    wprintf(L"%c\n", w_char1);
    wchar_t w_char2=0xE282AC;
    wprintf(L"%x\n", w_char2);
    wprintf(L"%c\n", w_char2);
    wchar_t w_char3='\u20AC';
    wprintf(L"%x\n", w_char3);
    wprintf(L"%c\n", w_char3);
}
```

This prints the following on the console:

```
e282ac

e282ac

e282ac
```

I've tried it both with and without setlocale. In the Gnome Terminal Preferences, under Compatibility, the Encoding is set as `Unicode -- UTF-8`.

Any ideas why the Euro symbol does not print?

Comment: The UTF-8 encoding is a sequence of bytes already, not a valid character code. If you want to keep this representation, simply `printf("%c%c%c\n", 0xE2, 0x82, 0xAC);`. The actual Unicode code point is 0x20AC.

Comment: Maybe see also https://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: do not use wprint and w_char. It was a old attempts to add more characters. But later UTF-8 was developed in order to avoid all problems of w_char (double API, need to rewrite all software, etc.). [Note: Microsoft changed too early, so it has the mess of many similar API depending size of characters, JavaScript has similar issue, but because UFT-16 may takes 1 or 2 units (of 16-bits)]. Modern world should not worries about such implementation details. Just use `char` everywhere (and UTF-8)

Comment: Is "UTF-8" a valid locale name on your system? It is rather unusual. Run `locale -a` to see valid locale names.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*This does not have a complete solution, but I think it provides some useful pointers towards a solution.  It being midnight here, I need to go to bed.*</sup>

The POSIX manual page for [`wprintf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wprintf.html)
indicates that you need to use an `l` modifier before the `c` conversion specifier:

> `l` (ell)
> Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a `long` or `unsigned long` argument; that a following `n` conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a `long` argument; that a following `c` conversion specifier applies to a `wint_t` argument; that a following `s` conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a `wchar_t` argument; or has no effect on a following `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G` conversion specifier.

There's then a question of whether a `wchar_t` converts to a `wint_t` — it probably does.

I ran into a problem that I had to compile with `-Wno-multichar` to suppress errors like:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-common wprintf37.c -o wprintf37
wprintf37.c: In function ‘main’:
wprintf37.c:9:23: error: multi-character character constant [-Werror=multichar]
    9 |     wchar_t w_char1 = '€';
      |                       ^~~
wprintf37.c:15:21: error: multi-character character constant [-Werror=multichar]
   15 |     wchar_t w_char3='\u20AC';
      |                     ^~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

You also should check whether the `setlocale()` operation works — it doesn't for me.  I used `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` and checked it; that worked.  I am using a Mac, and have `LANG=en_us.UTF-8` set in the environment.  And I'm still not seeing the Euro symbol.

*Hmmm…*

One of the rules of debugging when things are failing is "check every function that can report an error".  This code does that, and the result is as shown:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <wctype.h>

static void err_warn(int rv, const char *msg)
{
    fwprintf(stderr, L"%s: rv = %d (%d) %s\n", msg, rv, errno, strerror(errno));
    errno = 0;
    clearerr(stdout);
}

int main(void)
{
    if (setlocale(LC_ALL, "") == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to set the default locale\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int rv;
    wchar_t w_char1 = '€';
    if ((rv = wprintf(L"%x\n", w_char1)) < 0)
        err_warn(rv, "wprintf - 1");
    if ((rv = wprintf(L"C1 = %lc\n", w_char1)) < 0)
        err_warn(rv, "wprintf - 2");
    putwchar(L'\n');
    fflush(stdout);

    wchar_t w_char2=0xE282AC;
    if ((rv = wprintf(L"%x\n", w_char2)) < 0)
        err_warn(rv, "wprintf - 3");
    if ((rv = wprintf(L"C2 = %lc\n", w_char2)) < 0)
        err_warn(rv, "wprintf - 4");
    putwchar(L'\n');
    fflush(stdout);

    wchar_t w_char3='\u20AC';
    if ((rv = wprintf(L"%x\n", w_char3)) < 0)
        err_warn(rv, "wprintf - 5");
    if ((rv = wprintf(L"C3 = %lc\n", w_char3)) < 0)
        err_warn(rv, "wprintf - 6");
    putwchar(L'\n');
    fflush(stdout);

    char s[] = "€";
    if ((rv = wprintf(L"S = %s\n", s)) < 0)
        err_warn(rv, "wprintf - 7");

    return 0;
}
```

Output (on my Mac):

```
e282ac
wprintf - 2: rv = -1 (92) Illegal byte sequence
C1 = 
e282ac
wprintf - 4: rv = -1 (92) Illegal byte sequence
C2 = 
e282ac
wprintf - 6: rv = -1 (92) Illegal byte sequence
C3 = 
S = €
```

Note that the error reporting function clears the error status on standard output (`clearerr(stdout)`) and resets `errno` to zero — no standard C library function does that.  Before I called `clearerr()`, all the operations after the first reported failure.

I think that it may be necessary to use `u8'€'` or something similar.  Check [§6.4.4.4 Character constants](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4) and [§6.4.5 String literals](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5) for more ideas.

---

<sup>*Twenty-four hours later.*</sup>

This code is working moderately well:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <wctype.h>

static void err_warn(int rv, const char *msg)
{
    fwprintf(stderr, L"%s: rv = %d (%d) %s\n", msg, rv, errno, strerror(errno));
    errno = 0;
    clearerr(stdout);
}

int main(void)
{
    if (setlocale(LC_ALL, "") == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to set the default locale\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int rv;

    /* This now works */
    wchar_t w_char1 = L'€';
    if ((rv = wprintf(L"%x\n", w_char1)) < 0)
        err_warn(rv, "wprintf - 1");
    if ((rv = wprintf(L"C1 = %lc\n", w_char1)) < 0)
        err_warn(rv, "wprintf - 2");
    putwchar(L'\n');
    fflush(stdout);

    /* Still failing */
    wchar_t w_char2 = 0xE282AC;
    if ((rv = wprintf(L"%x\n", w_char2)) < 0)
        err_warn(rv, "wprintf - 3");
    if ((rv = wprintf(L"C2 = %lc\n", w_char2)) < 0)
        err_warn(rv, "wprintf - 4");
    putwchar(L'\n');
    fflush(stdout);

    /* This works */
    wchar_t w_char3 = 0x20AC;
    if ((rv = wprintf(L"%x\n", w_char3)) < 0)
        err_warn(rv, "wprintf - 5");
    if ((rv = wprintf(L"C2 = %lc\n", w_char3)) < 0)
        err_warn(rv, "wprintf - 6");
    putwchar(L'\n');
    fflush(stdout);

    /* This now works */
    wchar_t w_char4 = L'\u20AC';
    if ((rv = wprintf(L"%x\n", w_char4)) < 0)
        err_warn(rv, "wprintf - 7");
    if ((rv = wprintf(L"C3 = %lc\n", w_char4)) < 0)
        err_warn(rv, "wprintf - 8");
    putwchar(L'\n');
    fflush(stdout);

    char s[] = "€";
    if ((rv = wprintf(L"S = %s\n", s)) < 0)
        err_warn(rv, "wprintf - 9");

    return 0;
}
```

The output it gives is:

```
20ac
C1 = €

e282ac
wprintf - 4: rv = -1 (92) Illegal byte sequence
C2 = 
20ac
C2 = €

20ac
C3 = €

S = €
```

Notice how the successful values all contain the U+20AC.